# Quotient of numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose, the quotient of a number $(n-3)$ if divided by $4$ is $p$. How can we show that the quotient of number $(n+1)$ if divided by four would be $p+1$

Comment: With basic algebra? Or what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Euclid's division lemma,

$a=bq+r$ where $b$ is the divisor, $q$ is the quotient, $r$ is the remainder.

$n-3=4p+r$

Adding 4 on both sides,

$n+1=4(p+1)+r$

Therefore the quotient is $p+1$

Comment: Try editing this in mathjax, but you are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the edits!

Comment: Euclid's division lemma, seriously? $\frac{n-3}{4}=p \Leftrightarrow n-3=4p \Leftrightarrow n+1=4p+4=4(p+1) \Leftrightarrow \frac{n+1}{4}=p+1$. Valid in any ring in which the notations make sense to begin with.